# Drupal: MySQL SELECT all posts belonging to a specific forum

Tags: mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin, drupal-7

I need to select all the messages (first posts and replies) posted in an array of specific categories (forums) in Drupal.

First posts are stored in `field_data_body`, replies are stored in `field_data_comment_body`.

The structure of `field_data_body` and `field_data_comment_body` is the same, in the column `body_value` there's the content of the posts and in the column `entity_id` their unique ID.

The table `field_data_taxonomy_forums` contains the `entity_id` column and the `taxonomy_forums_tid` column (which are the IDs of the forum categories). The table `taxonomy_term_data` contains the columns `tid` (which is the same of `taxonomy_forums_tid` and the `description` column (which is the title of the forum category).

So, I'm looking for a query that allows me to select the body of the posts (both first posts and replies) and the description of the forum specifying an array of `tid`s (i.e. the IDs of the forum categories), that I'll manually find in the `taxonomy_term_data` table.

So, for example I'm looking for the query that allows me to SELECT the posts "belonging" to `tid`s `1456,7622,862` and the relative `tid` description.

Here's a screenshot of the `field_data_body` table :
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, it would be better for us to split the task into 2 subtasks:

1. Find the bodies of the posts, belonging to a particular tid.
2. Find all the comments of the body, belonging to a particular tid.

We'll need to use these tables:

1. field_data_taxonomy_forums
2. field_data_body
3. comment
4. field_data_comment_body

Database structure:

[image: Database structure]

**Finding the bodies**

```
SELECT
    taxonomy_forums.taxonomy_forums_tid AS tid,
    body.entity_id,
    body.body_value AS body
FROM
    field_data_taxonomy_forums AS taxonomy_forums
INNER JOIN
    field_data_body AS body
ON
    body.entity_id=taxonomy_forums.entity_id
WHERE
    taxonomy_forums.taxonomy_forums_tid IN (9);
```

**Finding the comments for the bodies**

Here we'll need comments table, that unites `field_data_body` and `field_data_comment_body`.

```
SELECT
    taxonomy_forums.taxonomy_forums_tid AS tid,
    comment_body.entity_id,
    comment_body.comment_body_value AS body
FROM
    field_data_taxonomy_forums AS taxonomy_forums
INNER JOIN
    field_data_body AS body
ON
    body.entity_id=taxonomy_forums.entity_id
INNER JOIN
    comment
ON
    comment.nid=body.entity_id
INNER JOIN
    field_data_comment_body AS comment_body
ON
    comment_body.entity_id=comment.cid
WHERE
    taxonomy_forums.taxonomy_forums_tid IN (9);
```

If you UNION these 2 queries, you'll get the list of posts and comments.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e730e/2)

Comment: Perfect. Bounty award in 12 hours. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To find reference to forum id you must add use of "forum" table (table establishing relationship of nodes to forum terms.)
Also it should be noted that forum id does not exist, it is a taxonomy id.
Here is an example to get only first message topic by taxonomy id(tid)

```
SELECT * FROM field_data_body fdb
LEFT JOIN forum f ON f.nid = fdb.entity_id
WHERE fdb.bundle="forum" AND f.tid=15
```

Note that the forum module works with comment core module wich means that only first topic message is stored in "field_data_body" and all replies are stored in "field_data_comment_body" table.

Hope it helps

Comment: Right when you were posting I was editing the question to add more details 'cause I investigated a bit

Comment: and to add also the replies (joining field_data_comment_body)?

Comment: You can not join directly on "field_data_comment_body" you must JOIN first on "comment" table to get the correct comment entity id.

Comment: Uhm, but I see an `entity_id` column in the `field_data_comment_body` table

Comment: The entity_id in "field_data_comment_body" table is an "id" of comment entity not node entity...
To find related node to specific comment you need the node id (nid) in table "comment"